# Why default operator for int? is not consistent?

Tags: c#, .net, default-value

Why `default` is returning different values? Is it because of null coalescing operator?

Code (FYI .Dump() is from LinqPad):

```
void Main()
{
    Foo foo = null;
    int? a = default;
    a.Dump("a"); // returns null

    a = foo?.Bar ?? default;
    a.Dump("a"); // returns 0

    a = foo?.Bar ?? default(int?);
    a.Dump("a"); // returns null

    (foo?.Bar is null ? default : "ADsf").Dump();
}

class Foo
{
    public int? Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This line of code: `a = foo?.Bar ?? default` implements a null check. It will implicitly cast it to an `int` value before assigning it to `a`. At least, that is my guess. Otherwise you say: `if null then return null instead` which makes the null check redundant.

Comment: Shouldn't you use `a.Dump()` ?

Comment: The compiler infers the type of the expression. For reference type and nullable type it will give null, for value type it gives 0... `default(int?)` will return `null` and `a = foo?.Bar ?? default;` will return `0` indeed.

Comment: The type of `??` depends on the operands and the conversions available. Because the `default` literal has no type in that context (its type is inferred from the target, which would create a circularity problem) the type of the expression as a whole becomes the type of the underlying nullable (`int` in this case) and that's what `default` becomes. Note that `foo?.Bar != null ? foo?.Bar : default` does result in `null`, because the type of the `? :` expression is inferred as `int?`.

Comment: @ArthurAttout The LinqPad extension method can accept a header string: `somevalue.Dump("my header");`

Comment: By a strict reading of the standard, `<nullable> ?? default` should be a compile-time error if `default` has no type (if `default` is to have *any* type, then surely it would have to be the type of the variable the expression it's assigned to, but that's clearly not what's happening). The [exact rules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/language-specification/expressions#the-null-coalescing-operator) for the null-coalescing operator would mandate an error if the right-hand side has no type, but the summary of the rules does explain the behavior. It may be a bug.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I don't think that's quite true. The default literal is documented: "an expression with this classification can be implicitly converted to any type, by a default literal conversion" at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-7.1/target-typed-default and the rules you link don't require the right operand to have a type so long as it can be implicitly converted to the underlying type of the left operand, and this is the highest priority rule not involving a compile error or dynamic types.

Comment: @Weeble: ah yes, that is convincing. It even says "the inference of the type for the default literal works the same as that for the `null` literal, except that any type is allowed (not just reference types)" and certainly `null` is no problem for the `??` operator (if the left-hand side is nullable) without it being mentioned explicitly as a special case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the simple variable declaration statement here:

```cs
int? a = default;
```

`default` is always the default value of the type that the variable is assigned. Since you explicitly declared `a` to have a type of `int?`, `default` will be equal to `default(int?)`.

Null-coalescing (`??`) of a nullable value type will attempt to return a non-null value type (your typical struct, in this case `int`).

Therefore in this example:

```cs
a = foo?.Bar ?? default;
```

`default` will be equal to `default(int)` as it attempts to return an `int` object through the operator.

And in this example:

```cs
a = foo?.Bar ?? default(int?);
```

since `default(int?)` returns an object of type `int?`, it will either enforce the left hand to be cast to `int?`, or `int?` be cast to `int`. Since `int` is implicitly cast to `int?`, the null coalescing operator will consider returning `int?` in this case.

Comment: I've read the documentation of null-ascending, but somehow I have not realized that. When I read your answer it became so obvious . Thanks for your help!